# CMake: Get the complete representation of a path minus relative elements

Tags: cmake

I want to take a variable that has been set to a combination of path elements (potentially both absolute and relative) and get the absolute path from it. Something like what `boost::filesystem::system_complete()` does in C++. For example, I have something like:

```
set(EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../external" CACHE PATH "Location of externals")
```

which works but in the UI it's a bit ugly, as it might end up looking like `C:/dev/repo/tool/../external`. I'm wondering if there's a CMake built-in command to turn that into `C:/dev/repo/external` before I go and script a macro to do it. `find_path` kind of does this, but it requires that the path already exist and something worth searching for be there. I want it to work whether the path exists or not (I might use it for an overridden `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` default, for example).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

```
get_filename_component(NEW_VAR ${EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR} REALPATH)
```

Answer (score 1):

As of CMake 3.20, you can use the [`cmake_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/cmake_path.html) command to normalize the path, which supersedes the `get_filename_component` command.

```
cmake_path(SET MY_NEW_PATH NORMALIZE ${EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR})
```

This also converts any backslashes (`\`) into forward-slashes cleanly.